# Is it possible to use proximity data to trim the start and end point of splines?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

#### Problem Description

After rotating, scaling, and translating curves which are oriented flat on a face's normal, there are many curves whose start and/or endpoints exceed the boundary of the face they lie upon:

[image]

Node setup thus far:

[image]

#### Application Goal

It would be nice if, after the curves were positioned, the exceeding curve portion could be trimmed off, regardless if it is from the start or end point.

Looking at the viewer node with proximity data from the box target to the splines, it looks like this task might be possible with a combination of proximity data and trimming, but I've failed to arrive at a solution:

[image]

If the proximity+trimming combo isn't possible, I'm planning to either resample to a high enough resolution to where I can remove points by proximity "close enough" to the edge of the face, or try to add points right at the intersection of the edges (via the method from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSkCTGc0ZTc&list=PLxfyspV_QT6WjLe4UPRbEmDrT-o1PvIOl&index=25&t=8s)). Still, if any other solution comes to mind I'd appreciate the ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this edge bisect node group

[image]

[image]

Comment: It will take me a while to understand all of the vector math- it looks like a really well thought out setup. Thank you kindly for the solution.